# Modus Operandi - Upload and Resize Multiple images using Zend Framework and HTML5

Tags: zend-framework, html, upload

The good news:

- I don't care if it uses ajax or not.
- I don't care if the user must install a specific browser to make it work.
- I don't care if there isn't any specifc progress bar.

The bad news:

- I don't want to use flash.

The user must upload a file from any width or height - however no bigger then 8MB.
The file must be stored on a specific folder (or database column).
A thumbnail must be generated on a specific folder (or database column).

Those images must be associated with a specific record.

This is a "modus operandi" question, I realise that there is to much code involved here.

So:

1. We first create our form element to support multiple upload, like this:

   ```
   $element = new Zend_Form_Element_File('multifile');
   $element->setAttrib('multiple', true);
   $element->setIsArray(true);
   ```
2. We then, need to add some validations and allowed extensions;
3. Then we need to process the upload;
4. Once the upload is done, we need to resize those multiple files according to our needs.
5. We need to store those resized files somewhere else.
6. Once all this is done, we are ready to display the files associated with a specific database record?

Is this the way to go? Should I have more steps? Am I missing something. I've never done this before, but I'm taking it like a challenge.

Comment: Yes, this is the way to do basic file upload. Are you having any specific issues with the code or are you just confirming the general steps to follow?

Comment: @mingos - I'm confirming the steps to go, once I have those clear, I will start to code. However, if I can have sixteen points instead of 6, that would be great. :) The point is to have much detail as possible. I will probably need to integrate PHPThumb into Zend right? What about the design patterns involved on such a process, should we create a helper to deal with the upload ? I will probably need to rename the files with some random names PLUS some record id, for later retrieval ?

Comment: I use ImageMagick. It doesn't require integration with Zend specifically. You just need to have it installed and enabled. Or you can use GD2. It's installed on nearly all servers. A helper is not really necessary. You can do it, sure, but it would be overcomplicating the code. Make it simple, and when it works, you can refine it. I'll stir up an answer based on my code (as soon as I dig it out).

Comment: @All - I marked migus answer as usefull, because it is really helpful and I know that it could give me a start. However, the main question still applies, How does those two players can play on a upload structure, even if basic: html5 + zend.

Answer (score 4):

First, you create a form. Not much complication here:

```
$this->addElement('File','Filedata');
$this->Filedata
    ->setLabel('Select images')
    ->setDestination('somepath') //define & create it somewhere earlier ;)
    ->addValidator('Size', false, 1024000)
    ->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpg,png,gif')
    ->setMultiFile(5)
    ->addValidator('Count', false, array('min'=>0,'max' => 5))
;
```

In the controller, you receive the images. They will have temporary random names, which you can keep later if you wish (I usually do).

```
$fileinfo = $form->Filedata->getFileInfo();
$path = 'somepath'; //make sure it exists
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
    if($fileinfo['Filedata_'.$i.'_']['tmp_name']) {
        $img = new Imagick($fileinfo['Filedata_'.$i.'_']['tmp_name']);
        // image processing goes here
        file_put_contents('somepath',$img);
    }
}
```

And that's it ;)

Comment: Thanks. That seems a nice place to start. The only difference is that, you are not using the html5 sintax, instead, you are generating 5 input fields am I right? ->setMultiFile(5) ? And probably, because of that also, you can iterate over those 5 records to give them diferent names, I must however, do the same with undefined number of multiple files. Perhaps a foreach could be the answer? Anyway, I will try to code now... and see what I get. Thanks again:)

Comment: I'd handle that in JavaScript: add an "add more" button and dynamically generate more file fields. The count validator can be removed in this case, or perhaps only set to a minimum, if you need it. Then, in the controller, you'd use a foreach and manually increase your iterator or just count the uploaded files and use a for loop - up to you.

Comment: +1. Wow. I did not know that you can use ImageMagick in PHP in this way:-)

Comment: @mingos - Thanks for your patience. The main point here, is indeed to have the benefit of HTML multiple input field to work for us, and with that, understand how could THAT be integrated into Zend. I feel like you answer my question about, how to properly start an upload, but not, how to follow a workflow using html5. But I may be wrong. I will mark your answer as usefull case it sure is. And I will dig a little bit more about this multiple input field, and how it works. :-)

Comment: @MEM: if you wish to use the HTML5 miltifile upload feature specifically, then indeed, this is not what you are after. The functionality is the same though, and it is confirmed to be working (this code snippet is extracted from a community portal with a 10k+ user base - no complaints so far :D).

Comment: @Marcin: I'm honoured to have earned an upvote from you, especially in the ZF category, where so far YOU have been my personal guru :D.

Comment: @mingos. Little exaggerated, but thanks :-). You are also very good.